# Find where a sum of cosine functions will become zero

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have a series of cosine functions with different frequencies and amplitudes like this:

$$ A_1\cos(2 \pi f_1 t) + A_2\cos(2\pi f_2t) + \cdots + A_n\cos(2 \pi f_n t) $$

Sometimes frequencies are multiples of the lowest frequenciy ($f_2=2f_1 $ and $f_3=3f_1 $ and ...$f_n=nf_1$), but sometimes they are non-related frequencies. is finding $t$ which makes the sum of all those cosines zero possible in one case?

Comment: Your question is vague...you should be more clear and provide some values and how your work.

Answer (score 1):

There may be no real solution if some of the $f_j$ are $0$.  Otherwise, there are always solutions, but numerical methods may be needed to (approximately) find them.